# Is Start (Dart framework) autoreload on the server side?

Tags: dart

Is [start](https://github.com/lvivski/start) ([Dart](https://www.dartlang.org)  server side framework) auto-refresh when one of our source code changed (just like PHP)?

Is [bulls_eye](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bulls_eye), [bloodless](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bloodless) and [express](https://github.com/dartist/express) too?

or if they are not, is there any Dart server side framework that able to do that (edit code, then test on the browser, without needing to restart the dart/server program)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this is not yet possible in Dart. If you change the code you have to restart the app.
I wouldn't expect this to work anytime soon.
A main feature to make this possible is to manipulate the code at runtime. This is planned but as far as I know not yet started.

**EDIT**
The above mentioned feature is necessary when you want code to be updated without loosing the current state of the application but that is usually not so important on the server because it should be (mostly) stateless anyway.

In Dart there's no need to restart the server app when only the client part changes.

If you really just want to restart the entire server when the code changes you should be able to do that by yourself. Create a console app that loads the server app into an isolate (spawnUri) and watch the source directory for file changes. In the case of a file change shutdown the server-app-isolate and create a new one.

Comment: yes, but i don't think that it would easy for me with my current skill .__.)/|| also, if I have large amount of lines on source files, I don't think that it would be fast to restart whole server (my experience with `rerun` and `ruby`)

Comment: Launching an isolate is not very hard (but also not yet documented much) but it would just need a few lines of code. Just ask here on SO when you encounter a concrete problem. Observing a directory recursively for changes is also implemented in the 'dart:io' package. Dart apps on the server usually start up fast.

Comment: I find it convenient to just use the keyboard shortcuts `ctrl+F2` in DartEditor to terminate and `ctrl+r` to start the app (with `menu > Run > Always Run Last Launch` enabled).